# How I can get the value of the input type radio using jQuery the value contains spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used this code I also used AJAX in my page

```
$html.='<div><p id="question" name="qid">Q.'.$result['question_no'].': '.$result['question'].'</p></div>
     <label style="padding-top:15px;">
        A <span style="padding-left: 15px;"><input type="radio"';
        if (isset($result['answer']) && $result['answer']==$result['choice1']) {
            $html.= 'checked="checked"';
        } 
         $html.=' name="answer" id="option" value='.$result['choice1'].'>'.$result['choice1'].'</span>
     </label>
    </div>
```

And the jQuery part is

```
var answer = $("form input[type='radio']:checked").val();
alert(answer);
```

The value contain spaces like 'primary key' but I got only primary how can I get value with spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is really simple you just forgot to put double quotes for the value attribute, value attribute must be wrapped in double quotes here is the corrected code,

```
$html.='<div><p id="question" name="qid">Q.'.$result['question_no'].': '.$result['question'].'</p></div>
     <label style="padding-top:15px;">
        A <span style="padding-left: 15px;"><input type="radio"';
        if (isset($result['answer']) && $result['answer']==$result['choice1']) {
            $html.= 'checked="checked"';
        } 
         $html.=' name="answer" id="option" value="'.$result['choice1'].'">'.$result['choice1'].'</span>
     </label>
    </div>';
```

Now the jquery will pick the value correctly

Answer (score 0):

hi here is a working solution for your problem. feel free to modify the code to make it fit for your needs

```html
 <!-- including jquery library -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        /* When input of type button is clicked then call this function */
        $("input[type='button']").click(function(){
            /* load value of input with name gender in a JS variable radioValue */
         var radioValue = $("input[name='gender']:checked").val();
            /* check if there is some value in radioValue variable... if there is no value then if block will not execute */
            if(radioValue){
                alert(radioValue);
            }
        });
        
    });
</script>
 
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Gender male">Male
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Gender female">Female
        <input type="button" value="Get Value"></p>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you ensure that the value comes in snake_case like `primary_key`, then process it to what you want after getting it with JQuery.
Something like:

```
var answer = $("form input[type='radio']:checked").val();
alert(answer.split("_"));
```